# What's the point of HttpUtility.UrlDecode

Tags: c#, .net, urldecode

What's the point of HttpUtility.UrlDecode when .net already decodes the querystring when you request it.

Is this a hangover from classic ASP or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be useful when you are getting content from another source which does not decode the data itself, as well. It is true that it is generally not needed, yes; but when it is needed, it's nice to have a Framework-level function that works as the complement to `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`

(*as a side note; I may be remembering wrong, but I don't think I used UrlDecode much in classic ASP, either.*)

Answer (score 8):

It is needed in case you received UrlEncoded data from other sources then querystring.

Answer (score 1):

It can be used for a variety of things. Such as, the user submits a form where one of the fields contains a url to another website. Before displaying it you want to make sure it's decoded so that it displays "nicely".

Comment: To go along with this: if you have a form that accepts a URL as one of the fields, you want to make sure to URLEncode that value before sending it to the server. Then, when displaying that value in the future on a web page, you need to URLDecode that value.